# UIScrollView how to set ContentInset and ScrollerInset

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

im not able to configure my UIScrollView.

[image]

The image above shows my view. The orange box is my UIScrollView and the blue boxes (plus the orange box) is the view that i want to scroll.

The View is 520px with and the UIScollView (as usual) 320px.

How have I to set the ContentInset and ScollerInset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but I'm guessing your scrollview is not scrolling as expected.

You need to set the contentSize property to tell the scrollview that there is more content than just the viewable area (e.g. `myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(520.0, 100.0);`)

If you want to start with the content centred as per your diagram, you can to set the contentOffset property. (e.g. `myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((myScrollView.contentSize.width - myScrollView.frame.size.width) / 2, 0.0);`)

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine for me, but why wouldn't it work with storyboard? I tryed out everything, but i got it never working with storyboard :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure the contentSize and contentOffset properties are not exposed using storyboards/interface builder. The only way to set them is in code.

Answer (score 3):

Since the heights of the scroll view and its content match, and because it does not appear from your picture that you would like to add an empty space to the content, you should keep the `contentInset` set to zero (as it is by default). If you would like the content's middle to be visible through the scroll view, set content offset to `(520-320)/2 = 100`, like this:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(100, 0) animated:YES];
// If you do not want to see the view scroll, change this ^^^ to NO
```